# Invertir un string sin .reverse(); en JS

Tags: javascript, string

Bueno resulta que tengo que invertir un String en JS pero el metodo .reverse(); no funciona en mi caso.

```js
function invertir_nums(numeros, numeros_i){
  numeros_i = numeros.reverse();
}
```

El problema es que no invierte bien el Array y lo ordena como se le da la gana. Asi que probe esto pero tampoco funciona.

```js
function invertir_nums(numeros, numeros_i){
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    numeros_i[i] = numeros[6-i];
  }

}
```

Comment: "Tampoco funciona"... por qué no funciona?

Comment: no tiene mucho sentido la funcion, piensa primero una solucion y ejecutala mentalmente paso a paso. debes tomar el ultimo elemento del array y colocarlo en uno nuevo. recuerda que la posicion es base 0, el ultimo elemento es n-1

Comment: Tu función en la que usas reverse esta mal hecha, no se entiende por que usas dos parámetros de entrada y uno de ellos es nuevamente asignado dentro de la función. La manera correcta de usar reverse() está en la respuesta que te dio @Bryro.

Answer (score 6):

Una manera sencilla de hacer lo que buscas, es iterar la palabra que quieres revertir de manera inversa.

Por ejemplo;

```js
var cadena = "Hola, mi nombre es Juan";
var cadenarevertida = "";
   
//Itero la cadena de manera inversa
for(var i = cadena.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
  //Voy concatenando el valor a la cadena resultado
  cadenarevertida += cadena[i];
}
console.log(cadenarevertida);
```

Answer (score 4):

Como comentas en tu caso no funciona `.reverse()`, esto es debido a que lo que inviertes no es un array sino un string. Si deseas usar este metodo con un string puedes probar haciendo algo como:

```
    function invertir_nums(numeros) { 
        return numeros.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    // funccion simple 
    function rev(str) {
        return str.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
    
   //sin reverse
    function revS(str) {
    return (str === '') ? '' : revS(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
   }
    //agregandolo un metodo a String
    String.prototype.rev = function(){
      return this.split("").reverse().join("");
    }


    console.log(rev("hello"));
    console.log(revS("hello"));
    console.log("hello".rev());
```

> la razon por la que el metodo `reverse()` no te funciona es porque es solo para revertir arreglos!

Answer (score 1):

Como comentó cardeol, tu lógica no tiene mucho sentido

```js
function invertir_nums(numeros, numeros_i){
var j=0;                   //variable para el índice de numeros_i
for (var i = 6; i <=0; i--){          //recorres tu array de atrás para adelante
    numeros_i[j++] = numeros[i];        //asignas de adelanta para atrás
  }
}
```

No programo en javascript, si tengo algún error en sintaxis por favor corríjanlo.

Comment: Esas asignando todos los valores de `numero[i]` a la misma posición de `numeros_i`, `j` vale siempre 0

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo corregí. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const invertirPalabara = (rev = "")=>{ //arrow function
   (!rev)
      ?console.warn("No hay una cadena de texto")
      :console.info(rev.split("").reverse().join("")) 
 }
 invertirPalabara() //ejemplo del warn
 invertirPalabara("México lindo y querido")
```

```
const invertirPalabara = (rev = "")=>{ //arrow function
   (!rev) 
      ?console.warn("No hay una cadena de texto")
      :console.info(rev.split("").reverse().join(""))
 }
 invertirPalabara() //ejemplo del warn
 invertirPalabara("México lindo y querido")
```

Comment: Sería valioso que comentaras cómo funciona tu respuesta, para que otros aprendan.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una forma de hacerlo, con un enfoque algo diferente.

Una vez para una entrevista de trabajo me pidieron algo parecido.

Aquí va mi código a ver si te sirve como respuesta:

```js
function reverseString(s) {
// Funcion reverseString(s) => string
//  s: string que deseamos invertir
//  devuelve: String

    const len = s.length
    // verificamos si el tamaño del string es par o impar
    const isOdd = len % 2;
    // calculamos la mitad del string para poder iterar solo hasta alli (esto es por mejorar un poco la eficiencia)
    // si es impar debemos redondear (redondeo por defecto o redondeo hacia abajo) 
    // eso significa que el carácter del medio (central) no cambia.
    const middle = isOdd ? Math.floor(len / 2) : len / 2;

    // Ahora guardamos el carácter central si el tamaño del string es impar,
    // en caso que sea par, no existe carácter central
    let center = isOdd ? s[middle] : undefined;
    let head = '';
    let tail = '';
    for (let i = 0 ; i < middle ; i++) {
        // Aqui básicamente vamos llenando la cabezera y la cola de forma invertida.
        // Leemos el string original de atrás hacia adelante y lo vamos almacenando.
        // Nótese que 'head' se llena desde el final hasta la mitad y 'tail' se llena
        // desde la mitad hasta el inicio.
        
        head = head.concat(s[len - (i + 1)]);
        tail = tail.concat(s[middle - (i + 1)]);
    } // fin bucle for

    // Ahora podemos construir nuestro string invertido usando head, center y tail
    const str = center ? head.concat(center.concat(tail)) : head.concat(tail); 
    // Finalmente devolvemos el resultado
    return str;
} // fin funcion

// Un par de pruebas usando tamaños par e impar:
let reversedString = '';
const evenString = 'QWERTY';
const oddString = 'QWERTYU'

reversedString = reverseString(evenString);
console.log(evenString);
console.log(reversedString);

reversedString = reverseString(oddString);
console.log(oddString);
console.log(reversedString);
```

Saludos.